# if loop is printing "else" clause even when the condition is not met

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am new to python and learning it. I have written the code to print `"utep"` value when all the three conditions are met in `if` clause, but however my code is printing both the UTEP values from `results1` as well as `else` clause.

Input:

```
results1 = [{'asv': 'apache',
             'qid': '110310',
             'state': 'Approved - Pending Remediation',
             'time': '2022-03-07T21',
             'utep': 'UEXC0031327'},
            {'asv': 'nginx',
             'qid': '110310',
             'state': 'Approved Pending Renewal',
             'time': '2022-03-07T22',
             'utep': 'UEXC0033886'}]

results2 = [{'ASV': 'apache', 'KB_QID': '110310', 'time': '2022-03-02T23'},
            {'ASV': 'oracle', 'KB_QID': '100178', 'time': '2022-03-02T23'}]
```

Code:

```
for val1 in results1:
    for val2 in results2:
        if ((val1['qid'] == val2['KB_QID'] and val1['asv'] == val2['ASV'] and
             val1['state'] == 'Approved - Pending Remediation') or
              (val1['qid'] == val2['KB_QID'] and val1['asv'] == val2['ASV'] and
               val1['state'] == 'Approved Pending Renewal')):
            print (val1['utep'])
        else:
            print ("Not found")
```

Output:

```
UEXC0031327
Not found
UEXC0033886
Not found
```

Desired output:

```
UEXC0031327
Not Found
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like you did any debugging, such as printing out all the values, or the results of any of those comparisons. Please indicate what you have tried so far to debug this.

Comment: Given your results* lists and your code, I'm not getting your actual output.  I get one ```UEXC0031327``` and three ```Not found```.

Comment: `results1` has to entries. `results2` has two entries. That makes 4 combinations. You print something for each combination, either in the `if` part or in the `else` part. Why do you expect only 1 printed line?

Comment: the reason i am using two "FOR" loops is to check if the QID, ASV and state matches from results1 matches with the results2 , then print UTEP value of UEXC0031327 when the condition matches. What said was right, it is making 4 combinations but i am trying to make the code only to consider "results2"

Comment: `else` clauses *are* executed when the condition is not met — that's is their whole purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Each of your arrays `results1` and `results2` has two elements. So, the `if` statement run 4 times. The condition is `True` in 2 execution times, and it is `False` in 2 others.

Your desired output has two lines. So, I guess that you want to compare the first element of `results1` with the first element of `results2`, then compare the second element of `results1` with the second element of `results2`. In this case, you need to use the `zip` function:

```
for each_value in zip(results1, results2):
    if ((each_value[0]['qid'] == each_value[1]['KB_QID'] and each_value[0]['asv'] == each_value[1]['ASV'] and each_value[0]['state'] == 'Approved - Pending Remediation') or (each_value[0]['qid'] == each_value[1]['KB_QID'] and each_value[0]['asv'] == each_value[1]['ASV'] and each_value[0]['state'] == 'Approved Pending Renewal')):
            print (each_value[0]['utep'])
        else:
            print ("Not found")
```